# Io_context error in Boost Library

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to build a chat room using by Boost Libraries. But when I'm trying to use `asio::io_context`, the compiler says:

> io_context is not an member of asio.

I built Boost 4 times and I thought maybe the problem was due to an installation failure on my part, but it doesn't seem to be.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string make_daytime_string()
{
    using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
    time_t now = time(0);
    return ctime(&now);
}

class tcp_connection
    : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection>
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> pointer;

    static pointer create(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
    {
        return pointer(new tcp_connection(io_context));
    }

    tcp::socket& socket()
    {
        return socket_;
    }

    void start()
    {
        message_ = make_daytime_string();

        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_),
            boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

private:
    tcp_connection(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
        : socket_(io_context)
    {
    }

    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/,
        size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
    {
    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    std::string message_;
};

class tcp_server
{
public:
    tcp_server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context) //error
        : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13)) //error
    {
        start_accept();
    }
```

Comment: Which version of boost are you using. I don't see io_context in 1.63 but see ii in 1.66

Comment: I am using 1.65.1 and i can't see to.. So should i install 1.63 or what is the alternative of io_context in 1.65

Comment: I could find very little. Like they may have changed io_service to io_context. Going back won't fix it from what I see. Try using io_service. Sehe will know. I'd have to do more research.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Things [changed in Boost 1.66:](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_66_0.html)

[image]

The [release notes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/net_ts.html) show the renamed/changed interfaces:

> Boost.Asio now provides the interfaces and functionality specified by the "C++ Extensions for Networking" Technical Specification. In addition to access via the usual Boost.Asio header files, this functionality may be accessed through special headers that correspond to the header files defined in the TS. These are listed in the table below:

[image]

Comment: Ah, fresh off the press. I'm installing 1.66 now. Thanks.